# Dynmaic Fields - Admin on Rest

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, dynamic-forms, admin-on-rest

currently I'm searching for a mechanism to creat dynamic fields in the admin on rest - framework. The input-environment should look like the example in the linke below.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove

I want to use it to create an 1:n or m:n relation and I'm seachring for a possibility to realise it by the framewok directly or (second choise) by a react an component.

Does anybody know if there is a possbility by the Framework? I could't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as Base to solve my Prolem I found this discussion

https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/695

I think with hind it's possible to get it